# Fetching data from three tables but getting error of SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am fetching data from three tables:

```
$result = $this->db->query("
    SELECT 
        `meetings`.*,
        `follow_up`.id as follow_up_id,
        `follow_up`.comment as follow_up_comment,
        `follow_up`.date as follow_up_date,
        `follow_up`.time as follow_up_time,
        SELECT first_name, last_name, user_mobile, useralt_mobile from users where id = user_id,
        (SELECT address FROM day_location WHERE `meetings`.assigned_to_id = user_id AND `follow_up`.date = date LIMIT 1) AS location_name
        FROM meetings
        LEFT JOIN follow_up ON `meetings`.id = `follow_up`.`meeting_id`
        WHERE follow_up.`date` BETWEEN '{$fromDate_formated}' AND '{$toDate_formated}'
            " . ($user_id > 0 ? " AND `meetings`.assigned_to_id = '{$user_id}'" : '') . "
    ORDER BY `follow_up`.id DESC
");
```

Error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1064
>   
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT first_name, last_name, user_mobile, useralt_mobile from users where id = ' at line 7
>   
>   SELECT `meetings`.*, `follow_up`.id as follow_up_id, `follow_up`.comment as follow_up_comment, `follow_up`.date as follow_up_date, `follow_up`.time as follow_up_time, SELECT first_name, last_name, user_mobile, useralt_mobile from users where id = user_id, (SELECT address FROM day_location WHERE `meetings`.assigned_to_id = user_id AND `follow_up`.date = date LIMIT 1) AS location_name FROM meetings LEFT JOIN follow_up ON `meetings`.id = `follow_up`.`meeting_id` WHERE follow_up.`date` BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-31' AND `meetings`.assigned_to_id = '1' ORDER BY `follow_up`.id DESC

Can you please help?

Comment: Copy/paste the error text here instead of posting an image.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Just pasted error instead of image

Comment: What does this `SELECT first_name, last_name,...` is supposed to do?

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: You should probably use `JOIN`'s instead of these sub-queries.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Needs to fetch user information

Comment: It looks like you're tossing a bunch of random selects into one statement, which is completely messing up the syntax.

Comment: you should add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for get the users information you should use a join

```
$result = $this->db->query("
        SELECT 
            `meetings`.*,
            `follow_up`.id as follow_up_id,
            `follow_up`.comment as follow_up_comment,
            `follow_up`.date as follow_up_date,
            `follow_up`.time as follow_up_time,
            users.first_name, 
            users.last_name, 
            users.user_mobile,
            users. useralt_mobile, 
            (SELECT address FROM day_location WHERE `meetings`.assigned_to_id = user_id AND `follow_up`.date = date LIMIT 1) AS location_name
        FROM meetings
        LEFT JOIN follow_up ON `meetings`.id = `follow_up`.`meeting_id`
        LEFT JOIN users on users.id = `meetings`.assigned_to_id 
        WHERE follow_up.`date` BETWEEN '{$fromDate_formated}' AND '{$toDate_formated}'
            " . ($user_id > 0 ? " AND `meetings`.assigned_to_id = '{$user_id}'" : '') . "
        ORDER BY `follow_up`.id DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, user_mobile, useralt_mobile from users where id = user_id,
```

With this:

```
(SELECT first_name, last_name, user_mobile, useralt_mobile from users where id = user_id),
```

Comment: Now getting this error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: That is because you are using a multiple select statement in another select statement: first_name, last_name, user_mobile, useralt_mobile. You should either CONCAT() those or duplicate the select for each of the selected columns.